# Vue re-renders momentjs dates before it modifies the array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a child that gets props from parent and  ,on button clicked, emits to parent via event bus.

On emit i launch method that fetches data via swagger-client.

The aim is to recreate array of activities after child click.

The activities items have date property that is converted to momentjs method fromNow. `{{myFromNow(item.date)}}`

The problem is that when i fetch fresh list (and set it to vm.activities), the topmost item's date gets refreshed  for brief second before it is substituted via new item on the list. I flickers new date and its visible with naked eye.

```
methods:{
    getActivity(){
    let vm = this

      this.$swagger.Activity.Activity_activityAll(
        {
          filter: JSON.stringify({
            order: 'Date DESC',
            include: [{
              relation: 'person',
              scope: {
                order: 'DateCreated ASC'
              }
            }
            ]
          })
        }
      )
        .then(function (resp) {


          vm.$set(vm, 'activity', resp.body['activity'])


        })
}
}
```

and the listener is on mounted

```
  mounted () {
    let vm = this
    this.$eventBus.$on('childAction', () => {

      vm.getActivity()

    })
  },
```

If i run debugger it clearly shows that fromNow is updated after 
`vm.$set(vm, 'activity', resp.body['activity'])` and list is updated only after end of method:
[image]

Do you have any idea what could cause it?

Comment: Can you prepare some simple jsfiddle, or please explain better relations between childs and main app in markup for example. I prepared some jsfiddle already but it's works well [https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/336947/](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/336947/) and it is pretty straightforward

Comment: @MaxSinev Thank you for reply. I found out that problem was in separate parallel call that i was making (and setting reactive variable). The breakpoint showed in question,changed (re-rendered) ,probably, next tick released by that separate call.  It seems that i have to put my `activity` in computed property and iterate over that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the other( parallel ) call that was triggering the re-rendering of all reactive data before first ajax call finished.

The solution is to modify data from `this.activity` in computed property by adding fromNow date to activities and iterate over that computed property.

Like this:

```
computed: {
    compActivities () {
      this.activities.forEach((item, index, arr) => {
        arr[index].ActivityDateInterval = moment(item.ActivityDate).fromNow(true)
      }
      )
      return this.activities
    }
}
```